# Picasso showing images after scrolling

Tags: android, picasso

I have a `searchview` and `recyclerview` , I share the xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchinput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:searchIcon="@null"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/searchinput"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Now I make request to web `onQueryTextSubmit(String query)`, I call a function in my adapter class where I do the following

```
 public void filterData(String query){
        query=query.toLowerCase();
        
        if(query.isEmpty()){
            images.clear();
            images.addAll(orignallist);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            
        }
        else {
         // This is main function
            getimages(query);
        }
    }
```

I here get images url in a separate thread from the web through jsoup and show it in the recycler view through piccaso, it works perfectly but it only shows when I scroll down a bit , I use this with piccaso in `onbindviewholder()`

```
Picasso.get().load(images.get(position)).fit().networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE, NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE).centerInside().into(holder.imageView);
```

How to show image without scrolling , thank you!

When search button clicked [image] , when scrolled down a bit [image]

Update : after adding more functions it is now showing only when the keypad pops up

Comment: Could you add your whole adapter code?

Comment: Try adding `notifyDataSetChanged` in both `if-else` condition or you can do same after `if-else`(may be the bug was you haven't used `notifyDataSetChanged` in else condition)

Comment: @VivekThummar  I used notifyDataSetChanged() in the thread , I think thats the problem , ok I will sort it out but why does  notifyDataSetChanged() gets automatically gets called when keypad opens ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that I was trying to use `notifydatasetchanged()` inside thread , so I passed activity to the adapter and implemented this :

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
 public void run() {
 notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
 });
```

Images where showing on scrolling or keypad opening because adapter items were getting recycled